# apache 2.2 rewrite rule to send all requests to /index.php/ only in the server (internally) with OJS3

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I am using openjournalsystems.com/ OJS version 3.

To remove /index.php/ from a url like mywebsite.com/index.php/myjournalname/foo/bar/foobar… , you are required to enable in config.inc.php the restful_urls = on.

Once you do that, the urls will be without /index.php/ but wont load pages until you generate RESTful URLs using mod_rewrite.

I tried the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I get the error "redirected you too many times" with some error 302 move temporary on network.

Adding [R=301,L] just to see what happens on the address bar url, the /index.php/ is added ok and page loads normally but now am not achieving what I intended to remove /index.php/

Comment: I believe the issue would be that `/index.php/` does not exist as a file or folder (the path is to a folder because of the trailing slash) and so apache redirects again and again because the initial conditions never match. You could likely use the `[END]` flag instead of `[L]` to terminate processing of rules.

Comment: Or really the use of pathinfo (ability to do `/index.php/whatever`) is used because mod rewrite isn't available. If you have access to it, there is usually a setting somewhere to allow passing the path information via query string in whatever CMS you are running.

Comment: [END] gives 500 Internal Server Error. Ill try to look into pathinfo. Note this part /myjournalname/ does not exist, but index.php exists and bootstraps the app